# Using REGEXP_LIKE in old style join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have PL/SQL query with old style joins (with using (+) ). And now I need to add left joined table with REGEXP_LIKE clause. How can I make this?

In ANSI-style the query look like this:

```
select
    *
from
    deals d
    left join
        auctions a on a.session_code = d.session_code
    left join
        auction_history ah on ah.auction_code = a.auction_code and
                                REGEXP_LIKE(ah.auction_code, '^[A-Z]+')
where
    trunc(d.operday) = trunc(sysdate)
```

And in old style I want to get something like this:

```
select
    *
from
    deals d,
    auctions a,
    auction_history ah,
where
    trunc(d.operday) = trunc(sysdate) and
    d.session_code = a.session_code (+) and 
    (a.auction_code = ah.auction_code (+) and 
        REGEXP_LIKE(ah.auction_code, '^[A-Z]+'))
```

But it doesn't return deals which session_code is null.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `REGEXP_LIKE` is a 10g feature, so there is no reason to use legacy joins. Embrace the ANSI joins.

Comment: Why should it return deals whose session_code IS NULL? You explicitly check for REGEXP_LIKE(ah.session_code, '^[A-Z]+) - this won't match NULLs. What exactly do you want to check for? You should also provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat, this query was written by an employee who is ill now and I can't do big changes without that emplyee...

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, I want to get deals whose session_code is null or whose session_code is not null, but auction_code of auction_history should be like '^[A-Z]+' P.S. I had little mistake in query, now it's correct.

Comment: Oracle recommends to use ANSI joins over the old proprietary `(+)` outer join syntax, so why use that deprecated syntax? And one disadvantage of the old `(+)` syntax is exactly that: you can't filter on the outer joined table properly.

Comment: @aegorov Seems that you wrongly translated `(+)` to ANSI syntax or vice versa. In case of left join `(+)` should be added to the right side column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually, you can filter the outer table but it's ugly :)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat: only if you use a left join on a derived table where the filtering is done in the derived table's select. But you can't do it "directly" in the "join condition"

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin, You write! But it's not a solution. I corrected the error in sample query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`REGEXP_LIKE` is treated as a regular function regarding legacy joins. Here's an example:

```
SQL> WITH main_table AS
  2  (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  3   SELECT 2 FROM dual),
  4  lookup_table AS
  5  (SELECT 1 ID, 'txt' txt FROM dual UNION ALL
  6   SELECT 2 ID, '999' txt FROM dual)
  7  SELECT m.id, l.txt
  8    FROM main_table m, lookup_table l
  9   WHERE m.id = l.id(+)
 10     AND REGEXP_LIKE(l.txt(+), '^[A-Z]+');

        ID TXT
---------- ---
         1 txt
         2
```

Still, I would advise against using old-style joins in recent editions.